# snapjs prevent close on element click

Tags: snap.js

I'm using [snapjs](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/) and from what I can see, there isn't a way to configure it so that clicking on the 'element' does NOT close the snap drawer. I'm using this on desktop exclusively, and closing the drawer when clicking on the main window is slightly odd, so I would like to remove this altogether, and rely on my own open/close buttons.

Is it possible to configure this, or at least remove the event listener after snap has added it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
tapToClose: false
```

Change this in your settings...